# Interacting with BLE from both android and iOS app

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have same app with two versions in android and iOS. In this app, I need to interact with BLE devices to find UUID of that devices. We want to make a predefined database where UUID of the devices will be saved. But from android app, I get mac address as UUID. In iOS app, I get a different UUID. How can I get the same UUID from both android and iOS app after scanning BLE?

Can BLE be made write protected? If yes, how is that possible?

Comment: The device address has to be equal for both apps, since it is defined in the firmwire of the device. Try to scan the device with your PC (if it support BLE capabilities) to find the correct address.

Comment: Is the device address same as mac address? If yes, then device address is restricted in iOS.